# Search 1000 numbers in 1000 workbooks

Tags: excel, vba, loops, find

I've looked for quite a bit for a macro/code to help me do this, and though I've found several hints around it, I couldn't find a solution. Maybe it's my inexperience with vba or that it's a unique situation that I haven't been able to customise these codes to work for me. As you can hopefully see from the other questions I've asked, I always try to attempot a solution before posting here, but this is situation which I've genuinely struggled with and hope it is something simple that you can help me with.

- My worksheet: *Book1.xls*, has a list of 1000 numbers
- In sheet: *Sheets1*, in column A, I want to find each of these numbers by looping through approx 1,000 files in 10 folders

> "DirectoryA\A",
>   "DirectoryA\B",
>   "DirectoryA\C",
>   "DirectoryA\D",
>   "DirectoryA\E",
>   "DirectoryA\F",
>   "DirectoryA\G",
>   "DirectoryA\H",
>   "DirectoryA\I",
>   "DirectoryA\J"

- everytime I find the number, I want to return the contents of the cell to the right of the number, and print it to the right of its corresponding value in Book1.xls.

Thanks as always.

Comment: Will each number in the original worksheet only appear once overall in the 1000 files or could it appear multiple times? If multiple, do you need all occurrences or just one?

Comment: There may be multiples - so I would require all occurrences!

Answer (score 1):

Here is one option that

- should be placed inside the Workbook that contains the numbers in Column A of `Sheets`
- it looks through the first columns of all files in a specified folder, searching for each of the numbers in column A
- any found numbers are returned from column B of the searched file
- these are appended in a variant array of the original numbers
- the variant array is dumped to a new sheet in the current workbook, then split into columns using `TexttoColumns`

If this does want you want it can be pointed multiple times at your 10 folders, or updated to loop through sub-folders of DirectoryA

*code*

```
Sub LoopThroughFiles()
Dim Wb As Workbook
Dim Wb2 As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim StrFile As String
Dim strDelim As String
Dim rng1 As Range
Dim rng2 As Range
Dim X
Dim Y
Dim lngCalc As Long
Dim lngCnt As Long

Set Wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws = Wb.Sheets("Sheets1")
Set rng1 = ws.Range(ws.[a1], ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))

If rng1 Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
X = rng1.Value2
Y = X
strDelim = ";"

With Application
.EnableEvents = False
.ScreenUpdating = False
lngCalc = .Calculation
.Calculation = xlManual
End With

StrFile = Dir("c:\temp\*.xls*")
Do While Len(StrFile) > 0
Set Wb2 = Workbooks.Open("c:\temp\" & StrFile)
For lngCnt = 1 To UBound(X)
    If Len(lngCnt) > 0 Then
        If IsNumeric(lngCnt) Then
            Set rng2 = Wb2.Sheets(1).Columns(1).Find(X(lngCnt, 1), , xlValues, xlWhole)
             If Not rng2 Is Nothing Then
                Y(lngCnt, 1) = Y(lngCnt, 1) & ";" & rng2.Offset(0, 1)
             End If
        End If
    End If
Next
    StrFile = Dir
    Wb2.Close False
Loop

Set ws = Wb.Sheets.Add
ws.[a1].Resize(UBound(X), 1).Value2 = Y
ws.Columns(1).TextToColumns ws.[a1], xlDelimited, , True, Other:=True

With Application
.EnableEvents = True
.ScreenUpdating = True
.Calculation = lngCalc
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi @brettdj, this is almost what I am looking for. The only problem I have is I want to search the whole workbook, not just the first column. I tried to change: Set rng2 = Wb2.Sheets(1).Columns(1).Find(X(lngCnt, 1), , xlValues, xlWhole) to: Set rng2 = Wb2.Cells.Find(X(lngCnt, 1), , xlValues, xlWhole) - but this returns a "object doesn't support this property or method' error. Are you able to help me tweak this section so that it searches through the whole workbook? Thanks!

Comment: All cells in column A of each sheets, or all cells in each sheet?

Comment: To clarify, I want to search in all cells in each and every sheet in each and every workbook. Many thanks again.